# How to display treeview structure for database data in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i am trying to display treeview structure for maintower and subtower (subtower has to be displayed under maintower) in mvc4. I used the below code in View. It displays structure like,

```
maintower1
    subtower1
maintower1
    subtower2
```

but, i want to display like

```
maintower1
    subtower1
    subtower2
```

Can anyone help me please?

```
 @foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.treedata.Rows)
{
    <div id="treeview">
     @if( maintower  != @Html.Encode(dr[0]))
     {
         maintower = @Html.Encode(dr[0]);

        <ul>
            <li>@Html.Encode(dr[0])
                <ul>

                     @foreach (System.Data.DataRow drow in ViewBag.treedata.Rows)
                     {
                       if( maintower == @Html.Encode(drow [0]))
                        {
                         <a href="~/Home/Index"><li> @Html.Encode(drow [1]) </li></a>
                        }
                     }

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      }
 </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the following steps please make sure your **ViewBag.treedata** is in order by its column 0 (**Order by ViewBag.treedata.Column[0]**)

```
 <body style="font-family : Arial; ">
   @{
     var name = "";
    }

    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.treedata.Rows)
    {
        <div id="treeview">
         if( name  != @Html.Encode(dr[0]))
         {
             name = @Html.Encode(dr[0]);

            <ul>
                <li>@Html.Encode(dr[0])
                    <ul>

                         @foreach (System.Data.DataRow drow in ViewBag.treedata.Rows)
                         {
                           if( name == @Html.Encode(drow [0])
                            {
                              <li>@Html.Encode(drow [1])</li> 
                            }
                         }

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
          }
     </div>
    }
</body>
```

Comment: One more help pls, for every subtower, i have to crates link in such a way that if i clik subtower1, it has to navigate to corresponding page and the same for other subtowers too. If i used <a href=' '> @Html.Encode(drow[1]), obviously the same page is displaying for all subtowers. can you please guide me that how to do it?

Comment: Please give me the full code that you used in <a href=' '>  for a link i need to know how did it looks like when you loaded in browser.

Comment: You have mentioned the URl as "~/Home/Index" in <a href=""> tag, so it will definitely goes to the in index controller only, then it will automatically return to View in Index action method, you have to pass the URl from the ViewBag.treedata for each row in it. Then can able to pass the url as <a href="@Html.Encode(drow [112])">. drow[112] is an example column index.

Answer (score 0):

You must use two loops one for maintower and one for subtower

Or something like that

```
@{var previousMainTower = String.Empty;
  var closePreviousTag = false;}
<div id="treeview">
    <ul>
    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.treedata.Rows)
    {

       @if(previousMainTower != dr[0])
       {
            if(closePreviousTag)
            {
                </ul>
                </li>
            }
            <li>@Html.Encode(dr[0])
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.Encode(dr[1])</li> 
            @closePreviousTag = false;  
       }
       else
       {
            <li>@Html.Encode(dr[1])</li> 
            @closePreviousTag   = true;
       }
       @previousMainTower = dr[0]
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's not a fully working code it's shows how you should figured it out.

In short you must check in each step of the loop if the current 'maintower' is the same as in previous steap and if it's equal then do not create it.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the update. But,I have already tried by using two loop, one for maintower and another one for subtower that is resulted as for every maintower, it shows all the subtower. But i want to display subtower equals to maintower only has to be display

Comment: If you want to use two loops in the second one (nested loop) you must check name of the maintower and adds subtower only if names are equals.